# Agregar expresión regular para validar email en un modelo de mongoose

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy intentando agregar una expresión regular y forme parte de las validaciones de `mongoose y mongoose-unique-validator` sin embargo no encuentro la forma de agregarlo. Lo podría hacer con `node` pero me gustaría tener todo centralizado. Quiero agregar una expresión regular de correo electrónico. Este es mi modelo

```
import mongos from 'mongoose'
import validator from 'mongoose-unique-validator'


const schema = new mongos.Schema({

    personal_data: {
        name: { 
            type      : String, 
            required  : [ true, 'El nombre es necesario' ], 
            maxlength : [ 50, 'El nombre no puede exceder los 50 caracteres'],
            minlength : [ 3, 'El nombre debe contener 3 o más caracteres'] 
        },
        last_name:  { 
            type      : String, 
            required  : [ true, 'El apellido es necesario' ], 
            maxlength : [ 100, 'El apellido no puede exceder los 50 caracteres'],
            minlength : [ 3, 'El apellido debe contener 3 o más caracteres'],
        },
        user_name:  { 
            type: String, 
            unique    : [ true, 'El usuario está duplicado' ], 
            required  : [ true, 'El usuario es necesario' ], 
            maxlength : [ 25, 'El usuario no puede exceder los 25 caracteres'] },
        email: { 
            type      : String, 
            unique    : [ true, 'El correo está duplicado'], 
            required  : [ true, 'El correo es necesario' ], 
            maxlength : [ 100, 'El correo no puede exceder los 100 caracteres'] },
        gender:     { type: Number, maxlength: 1 }
    },

    company_data: {
        role          : { type: mongos.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Role' },
        area          : { type: mongos.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Area'  },
        permissions: [{
            module: { type: mongos.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Module' },
            chmod:  { type: String, min: 1, max: 5, default: 'r' }
        }] 
    },
    engine_data: {
        password:   { type: String },
        last_login: { type: Date },
        addedBy:   { type: String },
        addedDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        modification  : [{
            _id       : false,
            user      : { type: mongos.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
            date      : { type: Date, default: Date.now },
            updated   : { type: Array }
        }]
    }
}, { collection: 'users' })

schema.plugin( validator, {  message: 'Ya existe el correo o ID {VALUE} en la base de datos' } )

const UserModel = mongos.model('User', schema )

export default UserModel
```

me imagino algo así

```
email: { 
            type      : String, 
            unique    : [ true, 'El correo está duplicado'], 
            required  : [ true, 'El correo es necesario' ], 
            maxlength : [ 100, 'El correo no puede exceder los 100 caracteres'],
            regex     : function( value ) {
              var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
              return re.test(String(value).toLowerCase());
            }
 },
```

No tengo idea de hecho si está en la capabilidad de mongoose

Agradezco toda ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para realizar una validación en tu campo `email` usando una expresión regular (así como en cualquier otro campo en el que requieras expresiones regulares), puedes usar el [validador incorporado](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html##%7Bblock.identifier%7D) de Mongoose: [`match`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#string-validators).

Una expresión regular para validar correo electrónico sería la siguiente:

```
/.+\@.+\..+/
```

Entendiendo la expresión regular:

- `.`: El punto representa cualquier carácter exceptuando los saltos de línea.
- `+`: Cuantificador que indica que del carácter anterior se pueden repetir uno o más.
- `\@`: Carácter escapado `@`, (código ASCII 64), valida la inserción de dicho carácter.
- `.`: El punto representa cualquier carácter exceptuando los saltos de línea.
- `+`: Cuantificador que indica que del carácter anterior se pueden repetir uno o más.
- `\.`: Carácter escapado `.`, (código ASCII 46), valida la inserción de dicho carácter.
- `.`: El punto representa cualquier carácter exceptuando los saltos de línea.
- `+`: Cuantificador que indica que del carácter anterior se pueden repetir uno o más.

Como se aprecia, es una expresión regular bastante sencilla que sólo requiere posicionar adecuadamente los elementos típicos de un correo electrónico.

Tu esquema de Mongoose podría quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
import mongos from 'mongoose'
import validator from 'mongoose-unique-validator'

const schema = new mongos.Schema({
    personal_data: {
        name: { 
            type      : String, 
            required  : [ true, 'El nombre es necesario' ], 
            maxlength : [ 50, 'El nombre no puede exceder los 50 caracteres'],
            minlength : [ 3, 'El nombre debe contener 3 o más caracteres'] 
        },
        last_name:  { 
            type      : String, 
            required  : [ true, 'El apellido es necesario' ], 
            maxlength : [ 100, 'El apellido no puede exceder los 50 caracteres'],
            minlength : [ 3, 'El apellido debe contener 3 o más caracteres'],
        },
        user_name:  { 
            type: String, 
            unique    : [ true, 'El usuario está duplicado' ], 
            required  : [ true, 'El usuario es necesario' ], 
            maxlength : [ 25, 'El usuario no puede exceder los 25 caracteres'] },
        email: { 
            type      : String, 
            unique    : [ true, 'El correo está duplicado'], 
            required  : [ true, 'El correo es necesario' ], 
            maxlength : [ 100, 'El correo no puede exceder los 100 caracteres'] ,
            match     : [/.+\@.+\..+/, 'Por favor ingrese un correo válido'] // <- Validación regexp para correo
        },
        gender:     { type: Number, min: 0, max: 2 } // <- Tipo number debes validarlo con max y min, (maxlength y minlength son para tipo string)
    },
    company_data: {
        role          : { type: mongos.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Role' },
        area          : { type: mongos.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Area'  },
        permissions: [{
            module: { type: mongos.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Module' },
            chmod:  { type: String, minlength: 1, maxlength: 5, default: 'r' } // <- aqui se usa maxlength y minlength
        }] 
    },
    engine_data: {
        password:   { type: String },
        last_login: { type: Date },
        addedBy:   { type: String },
        addedDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        modification  : [{
            _id       : false,
            user      : { type: mongos.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
            date      : { type: Date, default: Date.now },
            updated   : { type: Array }
        }]
    }
}, { collection: 'users' })

schema.plugin( validator, {  message: 'Ya existe el correo o ID {VALUE} en la base de datos' } )

const UserModel = mongos.model('User', schema )

export default UserModel
```

Como puedes observar he realizado algunas correcciones sobre tu esquema:

En el atributo `gender` tenías lo siguiente:

```
gender:     { type: Number, maxlength: 1 }
```

Dado que `gender` es un campo tipo `Number`, la validación debes realizarla usando `min` y `max`:

```
gender:     { type: Number, min: 0, max: 2 }
```

No estoy seguro de la forma en la que pretendes usar este campo, puse sólo 3 opciones (0, 1 y 2) para indicar el género femenino, masculino y otro. En el orden en el que se prefiera.

En el atributo `permissions` tenías lo siguiente:

```
chmod:  { type: String, min: 1, max: 5, default: 'r' }
```

Siendo que el campo `chmod` es de tipo `string`, la validación debes realizarla usando `maxlength` y `minlength`:

```
chmod:  { type: String, minlength: 1, maxlength: 5, default: 'r' }
```

Con las modificaciones sugeridas y usando el validador incorporado, seguramente lograrás lo que te propones.

Espero que esto haya aclarado tu dudas.